# Web Performace and Load Test on Cloud (URL-based) using Visual Studio enterprise 2017

Tags: performance-testing, load-testing, visual-studio-2017, web-performance

How to provide Username and Password for webpage, used for Web Performace and Load Test on Cloud (URL-based) ??

Hello all,

I am creating Web Performace and Load Test by using Visual Studio enterprise Edition 2017. My webapplication has Username and Password fields on the login screen. After Providing Username and Password; User need to click on  "Login" button.

Please let me know How I can design my test to inclide login finctionality.

I am refering [https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/test/performance-testing/getting-started/get-started-simple-cloud-load-test](http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/test/performance-testing/getting-started/get-started-simple-cloud-load-test) this URL for reference and for designing my basic test. now I want to create Web performance and load test for my application. However, login functionality is not explained on it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are learning this tool. 
About the tool, it is just simulate the browser requests which is got recorded during your navigation. Hence, to test your scenario you can follow below steps. 
1. Create web test in visual studio.
2. Open that web test and there is record button. Click on that. 
3. Record your workflow step by step. Once you are done stop the recording.
4. Step 3 will give you raw script that means the requests that you recorded will have hard-coded parameters like user name and password. that you need to parameterize it.
5. the script will be now available for loadtest, now you need to add load test file and define load pattern.

Now your loadtest file is ready to test.

Comment: Yes, I followed this procedure. It is mentioned here: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/test/performance-testing/run-performance-tests-app-before-release
However, my question is about creating Test ON CLOUD; in which we just provide URLs and no record-playback method.
 
How to provide Username and Password for webpage, used for Web Performace and Load Test on Cloud (URL-based) ??

Comment: Once you done with step 5 from your link. You need to follow the steps as mentioned in this link. http://www.thisdevmind.com/2015/06/16/how-to-parameterize-tokens-in-url-for-web-service-requests-in-visualstudio-webtest/

Comment: @Jagdishsonawane:The link shared by you is dead.